# swift access container button

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am relatively new to Swift. Here is my question:
I have a UIViewController that has a container in it. The container has its own ContainerViewController. The container is the header of the app and it has a button in it.

I would like to set the value of a Bool inside the UIViewController based on whether the button (inside the container) has been pressed or not.

I don't think passing a "mainVC" with a segue would make it: There is no point to make a segue as the two views are shown on the same screen.

Should I give both the view and its container the same ViewControllerClass?

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: The containing view controller is the contained view controller's parent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different solutions:

1. Call a method on the `ContainerViewController`'s `parentViewController`(=UIViewController)
2. Use the responder chain:

   - Implement `canBecomeFirstResponder()` in the `UIViewController` (subclass) to return YES
   - implement a `buttonPressed(sender:AnyObject)` (or something) method in the parent view controller
   - call `UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction("buttonPressed:", to: nil, from:self)` from within the container view controller

This will allow the method to "travel" up the responder chain until it find a object that implements the `buttonPressed()` method. This solution can be useful if you want to reuse the header view in other view controllers.

3. Use the delegate pattern. Create a delegate property + protocol in the container view controller and have the parent vc set itself as delegate in the prepareForSegue() method that fires of the embed-segue. This also gets the reuse friendly stamp.
4. If you are using Storyboards then you can also use an [Unwind Segue](http://blog.dadabeatnik.com/2013/10/13/custom-segues/)

Comment: Thank you for this really complete answer. The second solution works perfectly. I will also look forward for this "unwind segue" I did not know about.
I wish I could upvote this qualitative answer but I don't have enough reputation.
Anyway, thank you very much. This helped a lot.

Comment: Great to hear it works. You can still mark this answer as the one that solved the problem.